# Word for data set that holds up through outliers?

Tags: terminology

I'm trying to think of the word that describes a set of data that is large/diverse enough that outliers don't make much of a difference in interpreting the data. For example, the average of $\{4,4,6,3,5,4,3,4,5,15\}$ (which is $5.3$) is much more similar to the same data set without the $15$ (which is $4.2$) than the average of $\{8,5,6,18\}$ (which is $9.3$) is to itself without the $18$ (which is $6.3$). This term would be used as: "set 1 is more ___ than set 2 because it has a larger sample size."

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I'd say anything about differences between set 1 and set 2 other than the size. You could say that the *estimate of the mean* is more stable or robust (or that we have less uncertainty in it), perhaps.

Comment: You might be thinking of _robust._ However, that word is properly applied to tests and estimates; not to data. Maybe google it.

Comment: The term "robust" comes to my mind, but I am not sure if it applies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say something like:

"The **estimate of the mean** of Set 1 is **more robust** than that of Set 2 because Set 1 has a larger sample size."

You could also say *more stable* or *less uncertain* instead of *more robust*.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

“Padded”

I’ve never heard a term for this, but “padded” came to mind in about a second.

I think this word gets at the idea of having more usual values that diminish the outlier. It makes me think of a shock absorber. The statistical shock absorber lessens the impact of the extreme value.

Comment: This answers the question, but fails a sterner test. Without this context, I would have no clear idea what researchers meant if they wrote about a padded dataset. I agree with others who are implying that the question is the wrong way round. Describe procedures, not data.

Comment: @NickCox Being clear is part of being an answer for the question. The first thing that comes to mind when I hear "padded" in this context is bootstrapping, and I think it would be for others as well.

Comment: @Accumulation So, you're agreeing that "padded" is disqualified by other connotations?

Answer (score 0):

a phrase rather than a word

"resilient to the effects of one-time anomalies"

or 1 word "homogeneous"

a second suggestion for 1 word "alike"

Comment: Thank you! "Resilient" is what I was looking for!